# Is there a way to validate that the xml serialization attributes on my classes and properties conform to an xsd schema?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, xsd, xml-serialization

Is there a built-in (or 3rd party) mechanism/library/analyzer that can be used to validate that the xml serialization attributes on a class/property matches the schema.

I know that you can't do full schema validation without an actual materialized document, but in theory you should be able to validate:

- element names match
- namespace names match
- property types match
- property types have the correct nullability
- property types have `RequiredAttribute` or new `required` accessor if the property is required
- property types have the correct data annotations (min/max values for numeric types for example)
- enum types have valid values and names
- array types have valid maxOccures (>=2 or unbounded)

This is by no means a complete list, but just some examples. I am also looking for something similar for json serializable types.

The reason I would like this ability is that we have several systems we integrate with that built custom xsd's that dont work well with any of the code-generators. While I could do standard schema validation, I would need to materialize a ton of different xml documents (null vs not null, too many records in an array, etc). What I am hoping to do is:

```
[Fact]
public void FooRequest_ConformsToXsdSchema() {
    SchemaSet schemas = LoadSchemaSet("FooRequest.xsd");
    XmlTypeValidator validator = LoadValidator(schemas);

    var result = validator.ValidateTypeConformsToSchema<FooRequest>();

    result.ConformsToSchema.Should().BeTrue();
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("FooRequest", Namespace = "urn:FooRequest")]
class FooRequest {
    [XmlElement("FooName"), Required, MinLength(3), MaxLength(50)]
    required public string Name { get; init; }
    [XmlElement("FooDescription"), MinLength(10), MaxLength(200)]
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    
    [XmlArray("Items"), [XmlArrayItem("Item"), Required]
    public ICollection<FooItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<FooItem>();
}

[Serializable]
[XmlType("Item")]
class FooItem {
    [XmlElement("name"), Required, MinLength(3), MaxLength(50)]
    required public string Name { get; init; }
}
```

Another great option would be a Roslyn Analyzer.

Anything that can give us build or test errors letting us know if the .NET types do or don't conform the the schema.

Thanks!